# Python Scrapy - How can I scrape HTML files retrieved from scraped HTML files?

Tags: python, scrapy

Good day to all. I was hoping for assistance. I'm new to creating spiders and I'm following a video tutorial.

AT this point I am able to retrieve the HREF content in the HTML file being scraped. But I'd like to also scrape the HREF content from the URLs that have been retrieved from the HTML file.

Some guidance would be appreciated.

```
import scrapy

class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "FirstSpider"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
            "file:///Users/jor/Desktop/submitted project/rhf/index.html",
    ]
    
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    

def parse(self, response):
    for selector in response.xpath('*//a/@href'):
        print("hello")
        print (selector.extract())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy uses a callback system to make requests and separate the functionality for each response.

A href gives you a reference from the current page. You need to extract the reference with the use of `getall` method of the selector (for multiple values of the selector) or `get` (for the first found value).

The href gives you only the reference, this means that you will get the route from the current page. You would need to combine the current page URL with the href and make a `Request` object. The best way to do it is with the use of the `follow` method of the `Response` object. This method automatically performs a URL join of the `response.url` and the `href` and returns a `Request` object. Then you yield through those requests.

```
import scrapy

class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "FirstSpider"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
            "file:///Users/jor/Desktop/submitted project/rhf/index.html",
    ]
    
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.get_hrefs)
    

def get_hrefs(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('*//a/@href').getall():
        yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    pass
```

**Note:** But you are reading HTML files from the file system, so this algorithm will only work if routes in the `index.html` file correspond with the location of the files in your filesystem

Comment: I think I know what you mean and I'll see what I can do to decipher it. Lol. Truly appreciative with your input.